# How do I create an http request from Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, httprequest, twilio-studio

I'm technical, but not experienced in coding and could use some help. I need to create an http request from Twilio studio. I am setting up a phone survey for my client and I need to log both voice and number inputs from the call to a database. I already have the database set up externally. It logs responses with an http request from CLI curl. I'm using the following curl request successfully:

```
curl --data "q=1 -X POST localhost/test.php
```

When I try to duplicate the same curl request using the http request widget (no http parameters), I only get error 500 back. By the way, I know it's collecting the data correctly with the flow because I've had it collect and then read back to me successfully.

[Twilio studio http request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6r3v.png)

I have tried adding http parameters instead of putting them in the body as well. Nothing I try works. My guess is that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of http requests and thus can't duplicate it in Twilio.

Any help you could give me would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I assume the URL you provisioned in the  Stufio HTTP Request widget is reachable from the public Internet?

Comment: Yes, it's reachable from the public internet

Answer (score 0):

When you add http parameters instead of putting them in the body (see the capture below)

---

[image]

---

there is a big **red "Save" button** on bottom left corner, and a **gray (hard to see and easy to miss) "Save" link** on the right, above the trash bin.

The gray "Save" link needs to be clicked when adding each name/value pair of the parameters.

The red "Save" button is to be clicked at the end when you're done with the http widget.

Comment: I've tried this as well, and I can't seem to extract the data from the parameter. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the php I'm using:

`<?php

$q=$_POST['q'];
echo "q parameter = $q";

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'database', 'password');

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$sql="sql string here";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close($con);

?>`

Comment: With a tool like Postman or cURL you can replicate the POST request Twilio should make to your endpoint. Does your code work then?

Comment: I have done a cURL in terminal without changing around the code I posted above and got it to save into the database no problem. The problem I'm getting back from Twilio is a "Outbound HTTP Request Failed" and a possible cause they list is a badly formed response (or a 4xx/5xx error). I'm guessing it's an error 500 which doesn't seem to tell me much given it's such a generic error code.